# What library should be included to use TransparentBlt?

Tags: c, winapi, linker, gdi, visual-studio-6

What library should be included to use TransparentBlt?

This is VC98 (Visual Studio 6) linking to the Gdi32.lib. (Other GDI functions such as BitBlt link as expected), and the compilers compiles with out error or warning.

Even though the Gdi32.lib is included, yet the linker returns this error:

```
mtcombo.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__TransparentBlt@44
C:\Work\Montel\Targ2_12\guitest.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Apart from an ability to spell...

Comment: Be advised this function causes a severe memory leak on Win98. Not sure how relevant it is for you, but...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AFAIK, you will need the Msimg32.lib

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532303(VS.85).aspx

Comment: Ah, cool.  The MSDN documentation for VS6 says to use GDI32.LIB in the same place.

Answer (score 1):

Msimg32.lib

FYI you can search the functions on http://msdn.microsoft.com/library and at the bottom it will tell you what library you need.